When does the java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths error occur?
The error occurred while decompressing the gz file downloaded from the URL.
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code
:
The gz file is saved in the db table and then released.
No decompress-related errors occurred on the development server, but they occurred during operational deployment.
Please give me advice on when this error occurs and what I should check..
The decompress source is as follows.


public decompress(byte[] value) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    GZIPInputStream gzipInStream = new GZIPInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(value)));

    int size = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while ( (size = gzipInStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, size);
    }
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    return outStream.toByteArray();
}




This occurs when the data has been corrupted in transit. The transit may include simply reading the data on Windows without specifying binary mode.

Thank you for your reply. So, can this error also occur in the same situation?java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code -- missing end-of-block

Yes. That is also an indication of corrupted compressed data.

Do I need to specify binary mode when transferring (downloading)?

You would need to put in your question exactly how you are downloading the data, and how you are reading the data into your code. Is your code running on Windows?
